How do I repeat page header on every page except the first page of a report builder?
My client wants a long line to name the report on the first page, this line cut through the header of the report. The problem is that they also want to repeat the company's logo through each page but do not repeat the long line on the first page.
I tried many ways, including one way that was when I drew 2 logos, one at the header and one in the body. The logo in the header is just not displayed in the First page, leaving the body logo to do that can draw lines. However, it seems that the report Builder does not support the hide of the header at First Page, because even if I use IIF (Globals! Pagenumber = 1, True, False) to hide the header's value at First Page, it still leaves behind The space is as big as the logo.
This is my current report design

and I want company's Logo can repeat every page without a line "packing list"

It's not clear what you want the report to look like. Can you post your current report design and then what you expect it to look like.

@AlanSchofield I edited the question and added the image. I really want the First page to keep that layout, and the following pages to have a logo header part without line "packing list"
